# TypeError in numpy array when trying to replace negative numbers with 0

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting a TypeError when I try to eliminate the negative values in this array. I didn't have this problem in a previous iteration of this code, but I suppose that that particular data didn't have negative values in it. I don't understand how the data ends up being a tuple....is that a "feature" of np.loadtxt? Did I make it a tuple when I swapped the columns/rows in the zip function? I want to know how to fix this, but I'd also love an explanation as to how the data ended up being a tuple in the first place. Also, I feel like there is probably a more elegant way to do this than a "for" loop, and I'd appreciate any insight into that.

```
my_array = np.loadtxt(cw.my_Fname, delimiter=',', skiprows = 12, usecols = necessary_data_columns)

my_array = zip(*my_array)

i=0
for value in my_array[6]:
    if value < 0:
        my_array[6][i] = 0
    i += 1

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal, sample source file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace all the negative numbers by zero just do:

```
my_array = np.clip(my_array, 0, np.inf)
```

If you only want to do it in a specific column:

```
my_array[:, col] = np.clip(my_array[:, col], 0, np.inf)
```

**Note**: you can transpose your numpy array with `my_array.T` instead of `zip(*my_array)`, and the `zip` produces the tuples that you found out...

When you need to transpose the results from `np.loadtxt()`, just pass `unpack=True` and you get the same result:

```
my_array = np.loadtxt(cw.my_Fname, delimiter=',', skiprows=12,            
                      usecols=necessary_data_columns, unpack=True)
```

Comment: +1 - Also, if you want to operate on the array in-place, you can specify the `out` argument for `np.clip`.  E.g. `np.clip(my_array, 0, np.inf, out=my_array)`

Answer (score 2):

Python built-in `zip` doesn't really understand numpy arrays.

Instead, use `numpy.transpose`:

```
In [11]: x
Out[11]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.],
       [ 5., -1.]])

In [12]: zip(*x)
Out[12]: [(1.0, 3.0, 5.0), (2.0, 4.0, -1.0)]

In [13]: x.transpose()
Out[13]: 
array([[ 1.,  3.,  5.],
       [ 2.,  4., -1.]])
```

After that you are free to modify your array as you wish.

Comment: So the zip part changed my list-of-lists into tuples? Thanks!

Comment: The `zip` actually understands the numpy arrays, but as a normal iterator where each row is one entry...

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that by doing

```
my_array = zip(*my_array)
```

You've turned `my_array` into a tuple, rather than a numpy array.  Therefore, you're getting an error when you try to modify the tuple (tuples are immutable).

You seem to want to transpose the array. With numpy, that's just:

```
my_array = my_array.T
```

After that your code should work as is.

---

However, there's a better way to do this.

You're using numpy, so just do:

```
my_array = np.loadtxt(cw.my_Fname, delimiter=',', skiprows = 12, 
                      usecols = necessary_data_columns)
my_array = my_array.T

my_array[6][my_array[6] < 0] = 0
```

Or a bit more readable:

```
my_array = np.loadtxt(cw.my_Fname, delimiter=',', skiprows = 12, 
                      usecols = necessary_data_columns)

col = my_array[:,6]
col[col < 0] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make all changes on a list and then you can convert it back to a tuple if you want:

```
my_array = np.loadtxt(cw.my_Fname, delimiter=',', skiprows = 12, usecols = necessary_data_columns)

my_array = zip(*my_array)

my_array = map(list, my_array)           #convert list of tuples to list of lists

i=0
for value in my_array[6]:
    if value < 0:
        my_array[6][i] = 0
    i += 1
```